# Mysql Grouping of data and regular Expression

Tags: mysql

I have a table where codes are recorded by our providers after examining patients. Codes look like A11, B99, C68, A12, O87, F76, and so on. Now I need to create a report where these codes are grouped and counted. Groups should look like A00-B99, C00-D48, D50-D89, and so on. I have researched and found I might have to use REGEXP which I want to avoid as much as I can. Can someone please help to what is the efficient and optimized way of doing it?

**Table:**

```
 ID  Codes   description
  1  A11     Infection
  2  A01     Intestinal infectious diseases   
  3  H77     Intestinal infectious diseases    
  5  D98     Intestinal infectious diseases      
  6  D98     Intestinal infectious diseases
  7  A11     Intestinal infectious diseases
  8  A00     Intestinal infectious diseases
  9  A03     Intestinal infectious diseases
  10  D00     Intestinal infectious diseases   
11  D98     Intestinal infectious diseases
... 
...
...
...
```

**Desired Result**

```
code_group    Count
A00-B99       10
C00-D48       50
D50-D89       100  
...
...
...
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.com. You're supposed to show us what you tried. This looks like a homework assignment.

Comment: This doesn't look like homework, it looks like medical record stuff.

Comment: Is there any rhyme or reason to the groupings? I see in your example it is all As then it's All Bs and half of the Cs... then the other half of the Cs and Ds.

Comment: why first group is `A00-B99` why not just `A00-A99` ?

Comment: @Chizzle These are ICD10 (Medical Diagnosis Codes) groupings and report has to be run by these groups.

Comment: Right, but my question is this: Is there any programmatic groupings for these things? Or are they split arbitrarily? For example is it groups of 150 at a time ( A00 - B49, B50 - C99)

Comment: They are split arbitrarily by WHO (World Health Organization).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `case` statement for aggregation:

```
select (case when code between 'A00' and 'A99' then 'A00-A99'
             when code between 'B00' and 'C48' then 'B00-C48'
             when code between 'C49' and 'D99' then 'C49-D99'
             . . .
        end) as codeGroup,
       count(*)
from t
group by codeGroup
order by codeGroup;
```

Comment: I combined your solution with PHP to compose dynamic case statements. 

 
`$sql = "SELECT ( case ";
  foreach ($diagnosisCategories AS $category) {
   $splittedCategories = explode("-", $category);
   $sql .=" WHEN b.code BETWEEN '" . $splittedCategories[0] . "' AND '" . $splittedCategories[1] . "' THEN '" . $category . "'";
  }
$sql .=" end) as codeGroup, COUNT(*)";
`

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use MySQL's `LIKE` operator to do this, assuming the codes are all three characters long. Something like this:

```
SELECT "A00-A99" AS `Code Group`, COUNT(*) as `Group Count` FROM table_name as T WHERE T.Codes LIKE "A%"
```

This would return a row like

```
Code Group   Group Count
A00-A99      44
```

For the groups with ranges inside of a letter, you could break the code apart like so:

```
SELECT "B00-C48" AS `Code Group`, COUNT(*) as `Group Count` 
FROM table_name as T 
WHERE T.Codes LIKE "B%" 
OR (T.Codes LIKE "C%" AND SUBSTRING(T.Codes,2) <= 48)
```

More on `SUBSTRING()`: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring

To group all of your results together, use `UNION ALL` like so:

```
(SELECT "A00-A99" ... )
UNION ALL
(SELECT "B00-C48" ... )
UNION ALL
...
```

Hopefully that will get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why do you need these weird grouping codes. Even you are confused:  you wrote *Groups should look like A00-B99, C00-D48, D50-D89* but in your **Desired Result**

```
code_group    Count
A00-A99       10
B00-C48       50
C49-D99       100
```

so you've used wrong desired result group **A00-A99** , **C49-D99** because they don't match to the ranges you declared before.

Here is an example of how to group your table by `A00-A99; B00-B99 ...`:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/63229/3

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(LEFT(codes,1),'00-',LEFT(codes,1),'99') gr ,
    COUNT(*)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY LEFT(codes,1);
```

But if you really need those strange ranges as group I would suggest you to set another table like:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3eca4/3

```
CREATE TABLE myGroups (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
  minGr varchar(10), 
  maxGr varchar(10)
 );
```

and your query could be:

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT(g.minGr,'-',g.maxGr) gr ,
    COUNT(*)
FROM myTable t
INNER JOIN myGroups g
ON t.codes>=g.minGr
   AND t.codes<=g.maxGr
GROUP BY g.id
ORDER BY g.id;
```

Comment: These groupings are medical standards. I am going to give it a try! (thanks for pointing out the mistake in Desired Result section. I have corrected it.)

Comment: create grouping table then, trust me that is the best way